# What expression is it possible to replace "extends object " in a conditional type

Tags: typescript, typescript-eslint

When I define a helper type RecursivePartial

```
export type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Array<infer U>
    ? Array<RecursivePartial<U>>
    : T[P] extends object // ESLint error occurs in this place
    ? RecursivePartial<T[P]>
    : T[P];
};
```

I get error with content like this:

ESLint:

Don't use `object` as a type. The `object` type is currently hard to use ([see this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)).
Consider using `Record<string, unknown>` instead, as it allows you to more easily inspect and use the keys.(@typescript-eslint/ban-types)

I went through everything I could find on this problem. And I could not find what I can replace `object` with, in this particular case

I am wondering how to write such types correctly?

Comment: why you can use Record<string, unknown>?

Comment: Just suppress or ignore the linter error; it's not meant to catch this issue.  Actually I kind of hate that error; there's nothing wrong with `object` apart from being "hard to use" in some circumstances, which doesn't seem to be enough of a reason to throw errors wherever it is used.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can fix it with a different approach. `object` is non primitive, right?
Hence we can rewrite your function in this way:

```js
type Primitives = PropertyKey | boolean

export type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Array<infer U>
  ? Array<RecursivePartial<U>>
  : T[P] extends Primitives
  ? T[P]
  : RecursivePartial<T[P]>
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACgTgSwLYOAgbhAzlAvLOAe0jlAGkIQoAfKAI0MIBsIBDAOwChOIAPMQqSihIUAEoQAxgFc4WDBBitSCVkwA8AFQB8eKAG9OUKAG0YUBOygBrSoQBmUTQF0A-AC4nZ51D7AI7AAmOACCcHCsIOqW9hBwUACq2kZQrlBhEVESMnIKSipq6knJxp6a3r68-kE48MioClgpaeUwzime2bLymPloha3OyQC%20ANxAA)

If value is not a primitive - than it is an object.

Comment: There are more primitives than `PropertyKey | boolean`.  There is also `null`, 'bigint` and `undefined`.   But really the ESLint error is a bad one; there's no principled reason to disallow `extends object` in TypeScript, and the reason to disallow values of type `object` is not strong enough to spit out an error, in my opinion